# Clear ReadOnly textbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I need to clear/ reset my textbox1 which is set to ReadOnly= "true". I used a textchanged event in another Textbox2 to calculate a value for the Textbox1. The value in Textbox2 is not cleared on Reset. Any suggestions  ??..
My code for reset

```
  function resetForm($form) {
        $form.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select').val('');
        $form.find('input:checkbox')
             .removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');      
    }
```

my aspx code

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" />

     <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server"     OnTextChanged="Textbox1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: 1. Set readonly off
2. reset
3. Set readonly on

Comment: The set text on the text box with javascript is not affected by the readonly. The readonly have to do with the user input and not with the program - is not readonly for the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is that you probably **not** call the function `resetForm` with the correct form value. Because on asp.net there is usually only one form you can remove the form parametres and make your reset as:

```
function resetForm() {
        $('input:text, input:password, input:file, select').val('');
        $('input:checkbox')
             .removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');      
    }
```

[*] tested and working

Comment: ya its working for my page but only for enabled textboxes. here textbox2 value is not getting cleared. after postback , the old value is set again.

Comment: @kk1076 what post back ? If the values stays after the post back then you check if you set them again - use on code behind the `If(!IsPostBack){TextBox1.Text = 'some text'}`

Comment: In textbox1,I gave AutoPostBack=true to trigger the textchanged event. and the reset function loads the page again

Comment: @kk1076 as I say, check the `IsPostBack` and NOT set again this values. (or give here all the code to tell you more details)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$('#Textbox2').val("");
```

Write above line into reset function And call the reset method..

Comment: The id of the input control is change when is render, to get the rendered id you need to type `$('#<%=Textbox2.ClientID%>').val("");`. Also what is try to do, is a general clear function that clear all fields in the form.

Comment: Sry for late response. i just gave you an example. You can try with this $('input:text').val(''); OR $('input[id$="txtBox"]').val('') if id's end with txtBox as a example OR if id's start with then $('input[id^="txtBox"]').val('');

Comment: Better late than never, thank God I am still alive :)

Comment: Yeah, thnx for your funny reply :D